# Wrap a span or div around the first 10 characters of every row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Got a question regarding wrapping a div or a span around the first 10 characters of every row in my table.

```
<table class="category table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="categorylist_header_title">
                <a href="#" onclick="Joomla.tableOrdering('a.title','asc','');return false;" class="hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="<strong>Titel</strong><br />Klik om volgens deze kolom te sorteren">Titel</a>             </th>
                                                                        </tr>
    </thead>
            <tbody>
                                        <tr class="cat-list-row0">
                                <td headers="categorylist_header_title" class="list-title">
                                                <a href="/agenda-test/600-16-09-2015-hermann-wesselink-college">
                            16-09-2015 Hermann Wesselink College                            </a>
                                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                        <tr class="cat-list-row1">
                                <td headers="categorylist_header_title" class="list-title">
                                                <a href="/agenda-test/601-15-09-2015-hermann-wesselink-college">
                            15-09-2015 Hermann Wesselink College                            </a>
                                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                        <tr class="cat-list-row0">
                                <td headers="categorylist_header_title" class="list-title">
                                                <a href="/agenda-test/602-14-09-2015-hermann-wesselink-college">
                            14-09-2015 Hermann Wesselink College                            </a>
                                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                        <tr class="cat-list-row1">
                                <td headers="categorylist_header_title" class="list-title">
                                                <a href="/agenda-test/603-08-09-2015-metzo-college">
                            08-09-2015 Metzo College                            </a>
                                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                        <tr class="cat-list-row0">
                                <td headers="categorylist_header_title" class="list-title">
                                                <a href="/agenda-test/604-26-08-2015-st-ludger-college">
                            26-08-2015 St. Ludger College                           </a>
                                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                        <tr class="cat-list-row1">
                                <td headers="categorylist_header_title" class="list-title">
                                                <a href="/agenda-test/605-25-08-2015-stedelijk-gymnasium">
                            25-08-2015 Stedelijk Gymnasium                          </a>
                                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>


                </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the first 10 characters of every row is the date. I want to wrap a span around this so I can style the titles of the row in a bit more proper manner. But I only can do this via jQuery, so if anyone has an idea how to make this work, would be awesome!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Select table > select tbody > select td, iterate TDs getting the HTML, place a span tag at the beggining, and another one at 10th char, theres multiple ways to do this. Atempt this then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.list-title').each(function(i,v){
text = $(this).find('a').text();
$(this).find('a').html("<span>"+text.slice(0,10)+"</span>"+text.slice(10));
});
```

jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/Lgvd7to0/